# Read Out Text Messaging Notification

Tags: sms, notifications, text-to-speech

I just bought a new Galaxy S 4 over the weekend - I did some light googling on this topic, but no luck yet.

I want to know how to configure my Text Messaging Notifications.

Ideally, the phone would audibly say:

- *Message Received*
- (Optionally) Then it would read the subject line if there was one.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm). However, I'm not sure you can read out a subject line, since an SMS does not normally have a subject line. It DOES have a body.

1. **Create a Profile**. In the profile tab, `create a new profile (+ button) > Event > Phone > Received text`. Click back button (to create the profile).
2. **Assign a task to the Profile**. After you click the back button, a dialog will pop-up. Click `New Task`. Name it (e.g. Read SMS). In Task Edit screen, `create a new action (+ button) > Misc > Say`. In Text, type "Message received". You can also edit the Pitch (of the voice) or its speed. Click back (to create the action). *If you want the text body to be read*, `create a new action (+ button) > Misc > Say`. In Text, click the label button to the right, select `Text Subject`.

When you receive a message, you will be able to hear "Message Received", and the text body (if you added an action for that).